# Protractor page object definition not working as expected

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

I apologize for the slightly vague title, I'm not sure how exactly to word this.

I have my Page Object which, with one exception, works perfectly. Here's the excerpt:

```
module.exports = function(){
this.facilityList = element(by.name('facility')).all(by.tagName('option'));
this.randomFacility = element(by.name('facility')).all(by.tagName('option')).count().then(function(numberOfItems) {
    var rnum = parseInt(Math.random() * numberOfItems);
    return rnum;
}).then(function(randomNumber) {
    element(by.name('facility')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(randomNumber)
});
```

}

I can access and use `facilityList` just fine. But then I realized that I'm almost always doing the same thing to `facilityList` so why don't I just create another line to make it choose a random one. So I create `randomFacility` using the code from the main conf.js.

It didn't work. The error I see displayed is:

```
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

I'm confused. Is this saying I can't do all that processing in the page object to get the random one or do I simply have to manipulate facilityList in the conf.js and be done with it?

Comment: The error means that Protractor was not able to find `Angular` to sync with

Comment: But why would it show up only when I added the line starting this.randomFacility and when I get rid of that line, the whole thing runs perfectly?

Comment: Please show your conf.js, we need to know how do you call the `randomFacility` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to know the mechanism about how protractor to find element. Protractor only to start find element from page when protractor's **action** API be called, like `getText()`, `click()`, `count()` etc.

So when you define variable to represent certain element on page, when Nodejs execute this line, protractor won't to start find element from page:

```
// page object login.page.js
module.exports = function LoginPage(){
   this.sumbitButton = element(by.css('#submit'));
   this.countName = element.all(by.css('.username')).count();
}

// use page object in conf.js
var LoginPage = require('./login.page.js');
var loginPage = new Loginpage();
```

When Nodejs execute line `var loginPage = new Loginpage();`, all lines in function `LoginPage` will be executed.

When execute the **first** line, protractor not to find element from current open page,

When execute the **second** line, protractor will find element from current open page, But at this time point, protractor is possible to launching browser with a blank page, the target page have not been opened or navigated to.

To fix your problem, you need to define `randomFacility` as class's `Method`, rather than `Property`:

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.facilityList = element(by.name('facility')).all(by.tagName('option'));

    this.randomFacility = function() {
        return element(by.name('facility'))
            .all(by.tagName('option')).count()
            .then(function(numberOfItems) {
                console.log('count: '+numberOfItems);
                var rnum = parseInt(Math.random() * numberOfItems);
                console.log('random index: '+rnum);
                return rnum;
            })
            .then(function(randomNumber) {
                console.log('argument randomNumber: '+randomNumber);                
                return element(by.name('facility'))
                    .all(by.tagName('option')).get(randomNumber)
            });
    }
};
// how to use
pageObject.randomFacility().then(function(ele){
   return ele.click();
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it said that randomFacility().click() is not a function

Comment: Via test logging, it goes into the function itself, but never makes it to the `var rnum` line.

Comment: I made a mistake in my code in  `how to use`, I updated and enhanced the log. Please try again.